# How can I make my content 100% height?

Tags: html, css, height

Just a simple structure. Trying to make my content wrapper have a left and right borders and stretch 100% height. Seems simple but not working. Am I missing something?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

//HEADER

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <div class="header_wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="logo_wrapper">
                    <div class="logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

//FOOTER

```
        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>


</html>
```

//CSS

```
body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 line-height: 1;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-weight:300;
}
.content_wrapper {
 width:960px;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
 border-left:1px #ccc solid;
 border-right:1px #ccc solid;
}

.header {
 width:100%; 
 height:80px;
 background:#FFF;
 border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
}
.header_wrapper {
 width:960px;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto; 
 height:80px;
 border-left:1px #ccc solid;
 border-right:1px #ccc solid;
}
.logo_wrapper {
 width:187px;
 height:63px;
 padding-top:8px;
}
.logo {
 width:187px;
 height:63px;
 background:url(../images/bit_ball_ai.png) no-repeat;
 margin-left:20px;
}
```

thanks

Comment: When u say you want the content 100% are you saying you want it to look like http://mokker.azurewebsites.net/ where the header and footer are at the top and bottom with full content/background in the middle or do you want the content to actually be 100%. I ask because 100% content height with a header and footer will give you scrollbars as that content would actually take up a 100% of the viewport. Hope I'm clear there.

Comment: @C.Hazleton no. Just trying to create a centered 960px content area that is 100% height of the browser with left and right borders so it looks like there are to side bars. Like a left and right side bar and content in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Here's a surefire way of making something 100% height:

```
#element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

That will make it fill all available space, but if it needs to be relative or statically positioned, you'd do like you're doing:

```
#element {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

If that isn't working, it's because one of the parent elements isn't 100% height. From looking at your HTML it seems like the only parent elements are HTML and BODY, but you only define 100% height on BODY, which would still be constrained by HTML. So the next step would be to make sure your HTML and BODY elements both have 100% height:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html > body > #element {
  height: 100%;
  /* more styles */
}
```